# Не компилируется фрагментный шейдер

Tags: opengl, webgl, макросы, шейдеры, gles2.0

Есть два вот таких шейдера:

```js
 // Vertex shader program
 var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
  'attribute vec4 a_Color;\n' +
  'varying vec4 v_Color;\n' + // varying variable
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
  '  gl_PointSize = 10.0;\n' +
  '  v_Color = a_Color;\n' +  // Pass the data to the fragment shader
  '}\n';

// Fragment shader program
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  '#ifdef GL_ES\n' +
  'precision mediump float;\n' + // Precision qualifier (See Chapter 6)
  '#endif GL_ES\n' +
  'varying vec4 v_Color;\n' +    // Receive the data from the vertex shader
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = v_Color;\n' +
  '}\n';
```

Компилируются функцией: `gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);`

Вершинный шейдер собирается **без проблем**, а фрагментный **нет**. В консоль падает вот это: `Failed to compile shader: ERROR: 0:3: 'GL_ES' : unexpected token after conditional expression`

Код чужой и мне не понятны вот эти строки:

```js
'#ifdef GL_ES\n' +
'precision mediump float;\n' +
'#endif GL_ES\n' +
```

Сначала я грешил на видеокарту но она ни причем. Этот код взят из исходников книги и в сети никто не отзывался плохо об нем.

Помогите найти причину ошибки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить строки на:

```
'#ifdef GL_ES\n' +
'precision mediump float;\n' +
'#endif\n' +
```

Эти строки переключают точность вычислений на среднюю для WebGL, так как, похоже, [не все устройства поддерживают высокую точность аппаратно](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/12/Use-mediump-precision-in-WebGL-when-possible), а те, что поддерживают, всё равно работают медленнее.

Comment: в том то и дело если оставить только тело макроса то все работает, а без него нет, сможете объяснить почему управляющая конструкция макроса не работает.

Comment: кстати ваш код идентичен моему.

Comment: @perfect, нет, обратите внимание на третью строчку. Должен быть `#endif` вместо `#endif GL_ES`. Только что на всякий случай проверил на jsfiddle — такая же ошибка, если писать как у вас.

Comment: да действительно если эту строчку поменять то все работать начинает. большое спасибо за помощь.